# Installing Android zip in Eclipse3.5 sdk

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm having problem with installing Android with Eclipse 3.5 sdk.

Here are some specifications,

1. I have the Android 1.5 sdk zip file, and
2. And the Eclipse 3.5 sdk zip file.

I have tried installing android as a plug-in but was unable, please tell me the way so that I can install Android in Eclipse with the stated specifications alone.

Please note that I have the 'ANDROID ZIP FILE'.

Answer (score 5):

android-sdk-windows-1.5_r3.zip is not an eclipse plugin.

[Android Development Tools (ADT)](http://developer.android.com/sdk/1.5_r3/installing.html) is the Eclipse plugin for Android development.

Once installed (through the remote site "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"), you will have to edit its preference in order for that plugin to reference the SDK (191Mo that you have unzipped somewhere on your disk)

> 1. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Software Updates....
> 2. In the dialog that appears, click the Available Software tab.
> 3. Click Add Site...
> 4. Enter the Location:

```
  https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

> If you have trouble aqcuiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).
>
> ```
>  Click OK.
> ```
>
> 5. Back in the Available Software view, you should see the plugin listed by the URL, with "Developer Tools" nested within it. Select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Install...
> 6. On the subsequent Install window, "Android DDMS" and "Android Development Tools" should both be checked. Click Next.
> 7. Read and accept the license agreement, then click Finish.
> 8. Restart Eclipse.
>
> Now modify your Eclipse preferences to point to the Android SDK directory:
>
> 1. Select Window > Preferences... to open the Preferences panel (Mac: Eclipse > Preferences).
> 2. Select Android from the left panel.
> 3. For the SDK Location in the main panel, click Browse... and locate your downloaded SDK directory.
> 4. Click Apply, then OK.